# Google QR-Code API encoded URL wrong in .NET and C#

Tags: qr-code

I am using the Google QR-Code API to create a QR-Code that includes a URL. This is the URL I am using:

*https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chl=http://www.test.de/Web/Portale/Form.aspx?PortalId=1&FormName=DetailsForm1&EstateId=14490*

What I want in the QR-Code is: 
*http://www.test.de/Web/Portale/Form.aspx?PortalId=1&FormName=DetailsForm1&EstateId=14490*

What I get is: 
*http://www.test.de/Web/Portale/Form.aspx?PortalId=1*

So its cutting at the "&". Any ideas how to solve that?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5):

You have to escape for your URL part before parsing into chl parameter.

A simple way would be replacing `&` with `%26` for your url portion.

Try this instead: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chl=http://www.test.de/Web/Portale/Form.aspx%3FPortalId=1%26FormName=DetailsForm1%26EstateId=14490

Answer (score 3):

You need to URL encode the value of the chl parameter. Otherwise the & in that embedded URL will be interpretted as a delimiter for the parameters in the querystring of the outer googleapis.com URL.

If you are using Javascript you can use `encodeURIComponent('http://www.test.de/Web/Portale/Form.aspx?PortalId=1&FormName=DetailsForm1&EstateId=14490')` to do the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this, the solution was to use the following code:

```
Server.UrlEncode(string url)
```

Now it works perfectly :).

Thanks, *encoding* was what made it click for me :).